# ruby oo design question should i reopen the class or use extension pattern

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, oop

so I have an ruby object that i need to create as a pdf and excel row and cvs row

so far I've created a new class with a method to take in the object and do the necessary stuff to produce the pdf , excel , csv

I've been reading Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices and it mentioned the extension method so i was going to do but since this is ruby should i just be reopening the class in the another file and added the methods on there to separate them from the main class

so

file ruby_model.rb

```
class RubyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

then do

ruby_model_pdf.rb

```
class RubyModel

  def to_pdf
  end
end
```

ruby_model_cvs.rb

```
class RubyModel

  def to_csv
  end

end
```

or should i go with with the object extension pattern?

Cheers

Comment: why want to put to_pdf and to_csv out of ruby_model.rb? is their code pretty generic or model-dependent?

Answer (score 1):

You should put your methods in a module and include the module in the class. This way is preferable because it's easier to see where the methods came from (in a backtrace, for example), and it's easier to reuse the methods if it turns out that they can be used in other classes too.

For example:

```
module Conversions
  def to_pdf
  end
  def to_csv
  end
end

class RubyModel
  include Conversions
end
```

It might also be a good idea to put `to_pdf` and `to_csv` in different modules, unless it's the case that if you want to mix in one you always want to mix in the other.

This all assumes that the methods don't belong in the class itself, but judging from the names they don't.

Answer (score 0):

If the language feature works fine, then keep it simple and use it.

Design patterns are documented workarounds for cases where the language is not expressive enough. A Ruby example would be Iterator, which is made redundant by blocks and [`Enumerable`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Enumerable).